# How to display a NSDate in table column

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have one table with columns "name" and "date"

I want date to appear in format "dd/MM/yy" but it display like "friday 13 April 2012 12:00:00 AM India Standard Time".

I have following code:

Person.h

```
@interface Person : NSObject{

    NSString *name;
    NSDate *date;
}

@property(retain) NSString *name;

@property(retain) NSDate *date;
```

Person.m

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

@synthesize name; 

@synthesize date;

- (id)init {

    self = [super init];

    self.date = [NSDate date];

    return self;

}

- (void)dealloc {

    [name release];

    [date release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now while adding a data to table I have written following code

```
Person *data = [Person new];
[data setName:@"abc"];

NSString *dateStr = @"13/04/12";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
[data setDate:date];

[arrayController addObject:data];
[data release];
```

arrayController is the NSArraycotroller.
Adding Person object into arrayController after adding all entries in nstable 
[tableView reloadData] to update a table view.

But in table it displays "Friday 13 April 2012 12:00:00 AM India Standard Time"

Please Suggest any solution.

Comment: Please explain more explicitly the relationship between this "controller" and the tableview.

Comment: arrayController is the NSArraycotroller, adding Person object into arrayController after adding all entries in nstable [tableView reloadData] is called

Comment: Sure, I understand - I think you need to explain it better in your question.

Comment: Is there any option to set a date format "dd/MM/yy" to NSTableColumn in xib.

Comment: You have to find the formatter that's creating the text date for the tableview.  An NSDate object contains no format (or timezone -- it's UTC).

Comment: In your code you convert string to date using formatter. For display data in format "dd/MM/yy" you can use output string `[dateformat stringFromDate:date]`

Comment: Right.  Somewhere (maybe `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?) there's a `stringFromDate` call that's formatting the date for display.  That's what you need to change.

Comment: I think you need to add the string inspite of adding date

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using cell based NSTableView.

**If you want to achieve this via code:**

You should implement NSTableViewDelegate method:`-tableView:dataCellForTableColumn:row:` 
and after you've created a NSCell instance, set an formatter to this cell instance (Create an instance of NSDateFormatter and setup it), use `[NSCell setFormatter:]` method.

**Via IB:**

Search for NSDateFormatter, and then just drag & drop over the cell, which should display this date. It will also give you an option to modify date formatter behavior, but you want be able to change display format, because it is obtained from regional settings.